# Offline software to draw Sprites

Tags: gratis, graphic-design, animation

I want to teach the way of creating 2D custom Sprites of humans to the children that are about 10 years old. They can do programming by [MIT Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/) so they know basic concepts of animation. But I do not know what is appropriate software for teaching to them. Important features for me are:

- Animate with bones
- Can work offline
- Can install on Linux and Windows
- Free (gratis)
- Export to PNG
- Not to be very very complex

A software is preferred if:

- Be possible to draw images from scratch in it
- Contain library of elements of human body
- Be possible to use its output in famous game engines like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).

I saw [Spriter](https://brashmonkey.com/) but it is not free and also it is not used to draw images from scratch.

Comment: You might wish to check [these questions for sprites software with answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=sprites+answers%3A1). Not my area of expertise, so I do not say anything about possible duplicates – I leave that part to you :)